# Call class method from non-class method

Tags: objective-c, methods, nstimer, class-method

The following piece of code refuses to compile because the method: "FollowPlayer" is a class method with class level access. How do I correctly allow NSTimer to call +(void)FollowPlayer?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{zombie_size=4; timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(FollowPlayer) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];}

+ (void)FollowPlayer: NSTimer{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey.  Can you check that the method you are calling is `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` ?  Your code has it calling `scheduledTimerWithInterval` ... missing the `Time` part

Comment: Thanks! However, I have the error: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100003a58 when executing.

Comment: I think it may be because you are missing the colon after the selector name `@selector(FollowPlayer)` ... should be `@selector(FollowPlayer:)`

Answer (score 2):

Change the target from 'self' to [MyClass class] where MyClass is the name of your class.

Comment: Changing the target to [EntityZombie EntityZombie] exits my program with SIGABRT.

Comment: ... and probably also generates a compiler warning.  `[EntityZombie class]`.

Comment: and what the console/debugger say? :)

Comment: Obviously you're doing something wrong with NSTimer: 2011-05-17 14:35:24.957 PlayerTest[96443:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff708f8a18'

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's not just a syntax error?  Can you do this?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{zombie_size=4; timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(FollowPlayer:) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];}
+ (void)FollowPlayer:(id)userInfo { NSLog(@"Timer called with user info %@", userInfo); }
```

Comment: No I cannot. The program still exists with SIGABRT.